# How to specify template typename when couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘T’

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code to define my matrix class.
The minimum code is below.

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class mat {

public:
        mat(){}
    
        mat(unsigned int r, unsigned int c, T value) : mat_(r) 
        {
        for (int i=0; i<r; i++) mat_[i].resize(c);
        for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<c; j++)
        mat_[i][j] = value;
        }
    
        std::vector<T>& operator[](int r){return mat_[r];}        
   

private:
std::vector<std::vector<T>> mat_;           
};

template<typename T>
mat<T> identity_matrix(unsigned int size){
  mat<T> m(size,size,0.0);
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++) m[i][i] = 1;
  return m;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{        
        mat<double> m = identity_matrix(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Under compilation, the identity_matrix function gives the error
"couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘T’".
I understand the problem. But how to solve it? Is there any way to specify <typename T> as input argument?

Comment: ***Where*** do you get the error?

Comment: Exactly like you did it for `mat` on that same line.

Comment: `mat<T> m(size,size,0.0);` assumes `T==double`. Maybe you should make `identity_matrix` take a `default_value` parameter, which would unlock the deduction of `T`

Comment: [OT]: How about have have tag identity and use constructor, i.e `mat(tag<identity>, unsigned size);` and so `mat<double> m{tag<Identity>{}, 3};`

Answer (score 3):

You should add the template after the `identity_matrix` and before `(`

```
    mat<double> m = identity_matrix<double>(3);
```

Comment: I beg your pardon for my inexperience. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad it helps. Btw, your code has many warning you should try to remove them

Comment: Scheduled work.